# Update PayPal Express Checkout Payment with orderId before executing payment

Tags: php, api, paypal

So I made my research online, but I can't find any great explanation on how to use `Patch` method from the classes PayPal give for express checkout.

My checkout process work in 3Steps.

**Step1**
The page where everything begin is a simple "Cart Viewer page", Where there is a button "Checkout With PayPal"
When we click on that button there is a javascript post request sent to my server asking for it to reply back with a `PayPal Link` (Where customer will login and approve the transaction)

**Step2**
After customer approved and come back to my website with a `PayPal PaymentId`, I fetch this Token and gather customer information to autofill the form with the paypal confirm address they have on file

**Step3**
Customer select shipping method and click "PayNow" only then I will create a orderId to his name and send an Update to PayPal with shipping cost and `OrderId`

So here is some code

**Step3 Code**

```
//$PaymentId = PayPal Payement Id Customer Returned with from paypal
//PayerId = PayPal PayerId Customer returned with from paypal
//$SubTotal,$ShippingCost,$Tax,$Total,$NewOrderNumber = Are setted with appropriate values.

$PP_Payment = PayPal\Api\Payment::get($PaymentId,$PayPalAPIContext);
$PP_Execution = new PayPal\API\PaymentExecution();
$PP_Execution -> setPayerId($PayerId);

$PP_Transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$PP_Amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$PP_Details = new \PayPal\Api\Details();

$PP_Details -> setSubtotal($SubTotal);
$PP_Details -> setShipping($ShippingCost);
$PP_Details -> setTax($Tax);

$PP_Amount -> setCurrency('CAD');
$PP_Amount -> setTotal($Total);
$PP_Amount -> setDetails($PP_Details);

$PP_Transaction -> setInvoiceNumber($NewOrderNumber);
$PP_Transaction -> setAmount($PP_Amount);
$PP_Transaction -> setDescription('Order #'.$NewOrderNumber);

$PP_Execution -> addTransaction($PP_Transaction);
$PP_Payment -> setIntent('sale');

$PP_Response = $PP_Payment -> execute($PP_Execution,$PayPalAPIContext);
try{
    if($PP_Response -> getState() == 'approved')
    {
        //Stuff to do when transaction did go tru!
    }
}
catch(\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e)
{
    //Error Handeling Code Here!
}
```

So even though I set these two

```
$PP_Transaction -> setInvoiceNumber($NewOrderNumber);
$PP_Transaction -> setAmount($PP_Amount);
```

It does not apply to trasaction on paypal.

So I made some research on how to do that, and found out I need to use

```
$PP_Patch = new \PayPal\Api\Patch();
```

But there is no documentation on what to use to update invoice number and shipping
So I tried to improvise with the following code

```
$PP_Patch = new \PayPal\Api\Patch();
$PP_Patch -> setOp('add')
    ->setPath('/transactions/0')
    ->setValue(json_decode('{
    "invoice_number":'.$NewOrderNumber.'
    }'));

$PP_Payment -> update($PP_Patch,$PayPalAPIContext);
```

So does anyone has a litle bit of experience with this ? can someone point me out the right dirrection, Or simply a proper documentation that show path to use for the `setOp()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So there is no documentation at all, for patch method.

To find out the path you need, You will need to look at the create_payment method `JSON` and from there figure out what you need to add. In my case I needed `invoice_number` so I needed `/transactions/0/invoice_number`
We can see it [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create)
[image]

So since I didnt had the invoice number in the transaction. I needed to `patch` `op` `add`

```
$PP_Patch = new \PayPal\Api\Patch();
$PP_Patch -> setOp('add');
$PP_Patch -> setPath('/transactions/0/invoice_number');
$PP_Patch -> setValue($NewOrderNumber);
$PP_PathReq = new \PayPal\Api\PatchRequest();
$PP_PathReq -> setPatches(array($PP_Patch));
$PP_Payment -> update($PP_PathReq,$PayPalAPIContext);
```